# JFrame/JPanel's Dimensions are Incorrect

Tags: java, graphics, jframe, jpanel

So, right now whenever the `Game` class runs (which contains a `MainPanel` object), I get only a small box just big enough to fit the "minimize", "restore", and "close" buttons, rather than a 1280x720 screen. All of my other `JFrame/JPanel` combinations work except for this one, and I can't seem to figure out why. It is most likely just a small mistake, but I've been puzzled for far too long on this issue. Thanks!

```
 public class Game extends JFrame{ 
    public static MainPanel mp = new MainPanel();
    public static void main( String[] args){
        Game g1 = new Game();
        g1.play();
    }

    public Game(){
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle( "Game" );
        setResizable( false );
        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1280, 720));
        setLocation(dim.width/2-getSize().width/2, dim.height/2-getSize().height/2);
        setUndecorated(false);

        mp.setBackground( Color.BLACK );
        mp.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(1280, 720) );
        mp.setLocation(dim.width/2-getSize().width/2, dim.height/2-getSize().height/2);
        mp.setLayout( null );
        mp.repaint();

        getContentPane().add( mp );
    }

    private void play(){
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    setVisible(true);
                }
            });
    }

}
```

and

```
public class MainPanel extends JPanel{
    private JPanel jp = new JPanel();
    public MainPanel(){
        jp.setBackground( Color.BLACK );
        jp.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(1280,720) );
        jp.setLayout( null );
    }

    private void play(){
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using:

```
setPreferredSize(Dimension dimension);
```

use:

```
setSize(int width, int height);
```

setPreferredSize(Dimension dimension); don't work in JFrame and only work for components like JPanel.

I hope that helps!!

Comment: It seemed to have worked. What is the diffrerence between `setPreferredSize` and `setSize`?

Comment: 'setPreferredSize' is the preferred size for the window and 'setSize' is the setting the proper size of the window. You're just setting the preferred size on the window and java don't care for preferred size in window. You can check the javadocs online or the source code of jdk.